# Xamarin form webview Eval not calling javascript

Tags: javascript, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I use following code to load page to `MyWebView`:

```
private void DisplayLocalPage(string filename)
{
    var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
    html.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
    html.Html = ReadFile(filename);
    MyWebView.Source = html;
    MyWebView.Eval("alert(200)");
}
```

Page is rendered well - all scripts run too, but this alert isn't fired, what are possible reasons?

Comment: You should allow the permission to run scripts. Does it work if you write it in the document ready event of JS of the loaded page?

Comment: I put the alert in onload of body and it works.

Comment: Check out this  link : http://www.tipsabc.com/2016/xamarin-forms-communicate-javascript-webview-native-code/

Comment: wait, according to this: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/call-javascript/ there is no need to create custom renderers and so on, why then?

Comment: Its only required if you need some advanced options, also there is an ExtendedWebView by XLabs. Apart from that with this piece of code its hard to explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out why it might not work. The Eval is triggered before the WebView is fully initialized or web page is rendered, so the script is trigerred, but doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
webView.Navigated += (o, s) => {
     webView.Eval("alert('text')");
     };
```

Comment: an explanation of your solution is usually helpful

Comment: @happymacarts the explanation is in my answer.

Comment: Both @Kamil Smrčka and cuddlecheek are correct. The reason the JavaScript isn't firing is because the page hasn't finished loading. The description from the documentation (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.WebView.Navigated/) for the Navigated event is: "Event that is raised after navigation completes." So in the above answer Kamil is subscribing to the Navigated event (in this case the page load complete event) and executing his JavaScript after it fires.

Comment: @JohnLay That still does not work for me. No alert is displayed.